# Sqllite3 open exisiting database in android, failing with File is not readable Error

Tags: android, sqlite

My app is simple, I want to load the existing '/storage/emulated/0/Download/my_database' as readonly in the android app.

*But when I tried using*

```
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/storage/emulated/0/Download/my_database", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```

*It fails with following error*

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.sagar.towerlocator, PID: 7660
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sagar.towerlocator/com.sagar.towerlocator.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: Cannot open database '/storage/emulated/0/Download/my_database': File /storage/self/primary/Download/db_verizon is not readable
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: Cannot open database '/storage/emulated/0/Download/my_database': File /storage/emulated/0/Download/my_database is not readable
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:252)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:205)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:505)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:206)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:198)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:918)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:898)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:736)
    at com.sagar.towerlocator.MainActivity.loadDatabase(MainActivity.java:58)
    at com.sagar.towerlocator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14 SQLITE_CANTOPEN): Could not open database
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:224)
```

*`Note: Everything seems working if I store database under '/data/data/<package>/databases/' directory, but my requirement is to work from any other location`*

Please advice me.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons why you are getting `SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException`.
I believe you can check if the file is corrupted or not, by starting **adb shell** and then by running:

```
sqlite3 <your-db-name>.db
```

Also, since you are reading from external storage, have you declared read permission for external storage in Android Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Ref: [READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

Comment: Yes, Android Manifest contains that line and able to do sqlite3 <db>

Not sure why app throws exception when accessing from different location other than /data/data/.... directory

Comment: why is your file name `/storage/emulated/0/Download/my_database` and not something that ends with `.db` ? Have you also checked `adb shell > cd /sdcard/Download > sqlite3 my_database`. Can you tell output of this ?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, thanks for the response.
It has been fixed now, permissions issue.